# Semantic-UI-React Footer

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, node-modules, semantic-ui-react

I've been learning ReactJS for the past couple of days and have been trying to build a website using `semantic-ui-react` in ReactJS. I understand there are components that one can use now but I am stuck on what to do in a scenario such as the creation of a footer... typically, in my raw HTML, I would have the `semantic.min.css` file included and at the bottom:

```
    <div class="ui inverted pink vertical footer segment">
        <div class="ui center aligned container">
            <h4 class="ui inverted header">&copy; Copyright 2017 | All rights reserved | Blahhh</h4>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="facebook square icon big"></i></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="twitter square icon big"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/c"><i class="linkedin square icon big"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want to translate this into `semantic-ui-react`. Footer is a class not a component in react by default so there's no component for it... Which I assume means I have to make my own component and basically write the code above. My problem now is that I don't know how to make it render as if I was using regular old semantic.min.css. I read somewhere to download the css file and include it, but one, I don't know where to (`MyCustomFooterComponent` or `index.html`), and in doing that, am I not increasing by load times on my website. Would this mean that everywhere there's a footer, just for one small section of custom code, the entire CSS file is going to be loaded?

Also, after building, would there be a double-import scenario from my addition of the Semantic CSS and `semantic-ui-react`'s CSS?

Sorry for the long question but I'm new to this and I like to find out what I can before making a terrible mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using react-semantic-ui then you already include 'the old semantic-ui.min.css' already. See [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage).

Hence, create a component and put those code in render(), change 'class' to 'className' and then use it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But what do I import in my `MyCustomFooterComponent.js` file then? How does it know to reference that? Because for all other semantic components, the syntax goes `import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'` to use the button etc...

Comment: If you are using `create-react-app` then in your `MyCustomFooterComponent` you export that Component
`export default MyCustomFooterComponent;`
Then you can import from somewhere else `import MyCustomFooterComponent from './MyCustomFooterComponent.js'`

Comment: I think I've misunderstood what to do. Including `semantic--ui-react` does not automatically include the CSS. I have to manually include it and then the classNames would work? That's not a double inclusion? First from `semantic-ui-react` and then from `semantic-ui-css`?

Comment: > That's not a double inclusion?

Nope, Semantic UI React doesn't include any CSS now, it only generates valid markup.

Comment: @AlexanderFedyashov I meant if he followed the guide line in the link provided, then he had already include 'the old semantic-ui.min.css'.